# How to load a view through ajax with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to load a another page content below my current page when i'm clicking on a div.

When you click .work-item div it will get the id and fetch the data to that relavant id from work/getListData function so that function will return json encoded data object with relavant data. now I want to pass those into detail-view,php and show it below the .work-item div

please advice

//js

```
$(".work-item").live('click', function () {
  var id= this.id;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/work/getistData/',
    data: {id : id},
    success: function (data) {
      var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

//controller 
public function listpage ($data) { 
  //this will give a page
}

public function getistData () { 
  $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');
  $data = $this->helper->fetchList($id )
  // echo json_encode($data);
  return $this->listpage($data);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use the `$$`? Moreover, instead of echoing the `result`, I would recommend to `return` it.

Comment: @fab  $$ that was typo error, I've corrected.  I just update my function with passing the data which fetched .  listData() function returining a view. but will it possible to return that page through ajax ?

Comment: Well, you can either pass html as a result or a JSON object. Therefore, either the html structure is returned from the server or created locally via JS. Your `listpage` function can produce html code on the server-side. It depends on your use-case. Additionally, your `getListData` has a typo and is missing a `;`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then you should execute this piece of code inside your AJAX success function:

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = data;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is my first answer in SO.

Usually what I do first is to break the problem into small pieces. Test and if succeed then move forward.

**Step-1:**

```
console.log(id)
```

- In your JavaScript click callback, Make sure you get the correct id.

In jQuery:

`var id = $(this).attr("id"); //if your required id in HTML id element.`

`var id = $(this).data("id"); //if your required id in HTML data-id element.`

**Step-2:** I'm not sure your PHP function name is `getistData()` or `getListData(`).

**Step-3:** `var_dump($id)` in your PHP `getistData()` function, just be sure you received the correct id.

I personally think if you use `GET`, You can also send parameter like this:

In JavaScript:

`url: '/work/getistData/' + id,`

Then receive in php => `getistData($id)`

**Step-4:** I'm not sure why you use `$$` in

```
$$this->helper->fetchList($id)
```

**Step-5:** I'm sure the correct function is `JSON.parse()`

You should write:

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Ok then. Best of luck.